# Как в js преобразовать число 1.1 в 10, 1.2 в 20 ... 2 в 100 и т.д.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в js преобразовать число 1.1 в 10, 1.2 в 20 ... 2 в 100 и т.д.?

Нужно с целью повышающего коэффициента, но непонятно как его сделать (его формула).

Comment: `100 * (x - 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> преобразовать число 1.1 в 10, 1.2 в 20 ... 2 в 100 и т.д.

Предложу такой вариант "формулы"... :)

```js
console.log(test(1.1))
console.log(test(1.2))
// ...
console.log(test(2))

function test(v) {
  console.log('Без Math.round', (v - 1) * 100)
  return Math.round((v - 1) * 100)
}
```

Comment: Зачем `round` ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, запусти еще раз мой пример - увидишь. Хотя, может у тебя в браузере не будет дробей... Я смотрю в Опере.

Comment: Везде всё одинаково будет, с дробями. То что машинное вещественное число не может точно одну десятую представить округлением чинить не надо. Только хуже будет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, т.е. вернуть ТСу дроби - путь дальше сам?

Comment: Я считаю что да.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, значит у ТСа будет альтернатива - пусть выбирает что ему понравится больше...